# SQL getting multiple values from the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL that has multiple lines for the same id.

E.g:

```
ID     event_id     category_id   
1      1            3      
2      1            6
3      1            18
4      1            24
5      2            1
```

I am wondering how I would make an SQL query to achieve the output for each `event_id` it shows all the categories it is in.

E.g

```
{
    "event_id": 1,
    "categories": [3, 6, 18, 24]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I didn't add my code because I just simplified this to my actual problem and all the rest of my code is unnecessary. My code only currently gets the first value from category_id so it shows "categories": 3. It doesn't seem to go through event_id and find all the ones that start with 1.

Comment: You should also provide simplified code for the implied data your provide i.e. you should always provide a [mre] which includes providing your data as DDL+DML so we can test it.

Comment: ^^^implied should be simplified

Answer (score 2):

Is string aggregation sufficient?

```
select event_id,
       string_agg(category_id, ',') within group (order by category_id)
from t
group by event_id;
```

Comment: Ah! Lately I was wondering how to order the items in the aggregated string, but I didn't had a chance to look into it. Thanks for remembering me about it and showing me how to do it. Great. :)

Answer (score 1):

If by chance you're not on 2017+ (string_agg), here is a bit of a hack.  I can't seem to find a way to create a simple json array.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[event_id] int,[category_id] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,1,3)
,(2,1,6)
,(3,1,18)
,(4,1,24)
,(5,2,1)


Select event_ID
      ,categories = JSON_QUERY('['+stuff((Select concat(',',category_id)  
                                            From  @YourTable 
                                            Where event_id=A.event_id 
                                            Order By event_id 
                                            For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')+']'
                              )
    From  @YourTable A
    Group By event_ID
    For   JSON Path
```

**Returns**

```
[{
    "event_ID": 1,
    "categories": [3, 6, 18, 24]
}, {
    "event_ID": 2,
    "categories": [1]
}]
```