# Create view with JSON array based on many to many table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a typical table with users. I have also a many to many table where first column is UserId and second BusinessId. I want to create a view with users where their businessId will be as json.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(CAST(u.[Id] AS INT), 0) AS [Id]
             
    ,(SELECT BusinessId FROM [TableA].[dbo].[user_business_entities] WHERE UserId = u.Id FOR JSON AUTO) AS BusinessEntityIds
FROM 
    [TableA].[dbo].[core_users] u
```

But in view I get this:

| Id | BusinessEntityIds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"BusinessId":1925},{"BusinessId":1926}] |
| 2 | [{"BusinessId":15}] |

It's pretty good, but it would be best if json had only values, no key name i.e only ids without "BusinessId":

| Id | BusinessEntityIds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1925, 1926] |
| 2 | [15] |

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll need to build this array using string-based approach. Currently, building a JSON array of scalar values is not possible using `FOR JSON`. What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699084/sql-getting-multiple-values-from-the-same-id/66699628#66699628   Gordon's answer is for 2017+ while my answer will support <2017

Comment: @DaleK OP is looking for a simple ARRAY.   Not clear why MS excluded that functionality.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for the reply, but I guess I'll leave the old way. I was hoping it could be done easier.

Comment: @Zhorov it's 15.0

Comment: @KrystianWolański Really not so bad.  Take a peek at the two options provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick options:  First is for <=2016 and the 2nd is 2017+

Never understood why MS never provided this functionality of a simple ARRAY.

**Option 1 <=2016**

```
Select ID
      ,BusinessEntityIds = '['+stuff((Select concat(',',BusinessEntityIds)  
                                       From  YourTable 
                                       Where ID=A.ID
                                       For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')+']'

    From  YourTable A
    Group By ID
```

**Option 2 2017+**

```
select ID,
       BusinessEntityIds = '['+string_agg(BusinessEntityIds, ',') +']'
from YourTable
group by ID
```

**Both Results Are**

```
ID  BusinessEntityIds
1   [1925,1926]
2   [15]
```

Comment: In my case it will look like this:

(SELECT '['+string_agg(BusinessId, ',') +']' FROM [TableA].[dbo].[user_business_entities] WHERE UserId = u.Id) AS BusinessEntityIds

Comment: Note that for text you would want `'[' + string_agg('"' + string_escape(SomeValue, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'`