# SQL Server select to json, column name as key and unique values of column as list value

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

For an SQL table like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Xxx | Yyyy |
| Xxx | zzzz |
| Rrr | Yyyy |

I want to retrieve a JSON result like this

```
{"Column A": ["Xxx", "Rrr"], 
 "Column B": ["Yyyyy", "zzzz"]}
```

The unique/distinct values of each column should be an array element added as value to the JSON key.

Edit:
Note : SQL Server version is prior to 2017.

Edit 2:

1. Distinct values for each column in table should be selected.
2. The selected distinct value should be converted into a list.
3. All the column names should be converted as JSON key and the list values should become JSON value.

Comment: This would require a bit of string manipulation.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511213/how-to-convert-json-to-array-of-strings/70511399#70511399  or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154957/create-view-with-json-array-based-on-many-to-many-table/68155076#68155076

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70511399/14015737) to your needs.

```
SELECT "Column A" = JSON_QUERY('["'+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('","',STRING_ESCAPE("Column A",'json'))  
                                             FROM  mytable
                                              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,3,'')+'"]'),
       "Column B" = JSON_QUERY('["'+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('","',STRING_ESCAPE("Column B",'json'))  
                                             FROM  mytable
                                              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,3,'')+'"]')
   FOR JSON PATH, Without_Array_Wrapper
```

That yields the result

| JSON |
| --- |
| {"Column A":["Rrr","Xxx"],"Column B":["Yyyy","zzzz"]} |

Also see it in action in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vvNZBy-O) (SQL Server 2016).

---

Detailed explanation, from the inside out:

- [`STRING_ESCAPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-escape-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ensures that the selected values are properly escaped to be valid JSON values.
- [`FOR XML PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016) returns the results of the inner query as XML instead of a rowset.
- `DISTINCT` makes sure you only have each element once.
- `CONCAT` joins commas and double quotes.
- [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) removes the unnecessary leading comma that was added by `CONCAT`.
- Outer double quotes and brackets are added.
- [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) yields an object from the constructed JSON string.
- Finally, the outer [`FOR JSON PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016) joins the constructed columns into one JSON.

See individual steps in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qF3h5dqN).

---

You could also use dynamic SQL, as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463450/14015737) to do this automatically for all columns in your table:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = ''
DECLARE @tablename as VARCHAR(255) = 'mytable'

SELECT @sql = @sql + ',[' + c.name + '] = (SELECT JSON_QUERY(''["''+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT concat(''","'',STRING_ESCAPE([' + c.name + '],''json''))  
                                             FROM  ' + t.name + '
                                              FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,3,'''')+''"]''))' 
  FROM sys.columns c
  JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
 WHERE t.name = @tablename
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '') + ' FOR JSON PATH, Without_Array_Wrapper'
  
EXEC (@sql)
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ttDdjssw) for an example with five source columns.